# Changing size of section erase the dot

Tags: sectioning, size

Hi when I try to change the size of sections, the dot which must be stand near the section number is disappear.

1. SECTION >TURN> 1 SECTION

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
   \titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
   \begin{document}

   \section{Test Section}
    test

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: and I don't know to format code in a question.

Comment: `\thesection.` ?

Comment: @samcarter Would you please write your comment as an answer and be more specific?

Comment: @RuixiZhang Thanks for the suggestion. I see that you already have a deleted answer with the same suggestion - please undelete it! I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 3):

As @samcarter pointed out, the dot you desired is missing in `\titleformat{\section}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}% The missing dot
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
 test

\end{document}
```